# How can i split a list of lists, so that every list is on an own row?

Tags: python, list

When i am reading a CSV file it prints out all the lists on the same row, i do not know how to split them into separate rows list by list.

It prints out like this:

```
[[1, 1, 2.2, 1.3, 9.6], [1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 7.6], [1, 3, 2.7, 1.5, 2.2], [2, 1, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5], [2, 2, 3.1, 3.1, 4.0], [2, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.0], [3, 1, 1.9, 1.8, 4.5], [3, 2, 1.1, 0.5, 2.3], [3, 3, 3.5, 2.0, 7.5], [4, 1, 2.9, 2.7, 3.2], [4, 2, 4.5, 4.8, 6.5], [4, 3, 1.2, 1.8, 2.7]]
```

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example of what you expected to happen?

Comment: Look at my edit, i want it to be row by row(but still the brackets on the sides)

Comment: That's just how lists are printed... When you print a list, it prints all the elements on one line with commas between each. You can iterate over them and print each element individually to get the printout you want. You don't need to append or manipulate anything... Just print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print it as you want:

```
x = [[1, 1, 2.2, 1.3, 9.6], [1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 7.6], [1, 3, 2.7, 1.5, 2.2], [2, 1, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5], [2, 2, 3.1, 3.1, 4.0], [2, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.0], [3, 1, 1.9, 1.8, 4.5], [3, 2, 1.1, 0.5, 2.3], [3, 3, 3.5, 2.0, 7.5], [4, 1, 2.9, 2.7, 3.2], [4, 2, 4.5, 4.8, 6.5], [4, 3, 1.2, 1.8, 2.7]]
y = '\n'.join([','.join([str(z) for z in y]) for y in x])
print y
```

Print it or write y to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a list of lists. When you print something like that, you will, by default, get all the values on one line because that's how `list.__repr__` works. If you want to print in some other format, you'll have to do it yourself.

Here's an approach that will print exactly like your suggested output:

```
for inner in list_of_lists:
    print(*inner, sep=',')
```

This is using the `print` function from Python 3. If you're using Python 2 I'd recoment getting access to it with `from __future__ import print_function` (though you could also use `str.join` to build your output and then use a Python 2 `print` statement).